# Effective use of enable_if with C++ templates to avoid class specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I am having trouble getting my code to compile.  clang, g++ and icpc all give different error messages,

A bit of background before getting to the question itself:

I am working now on a template class hierarchy for working with Matrices.  There are template parameters for the data type (either float or double) and for "Implementation Policy" -- at present this includes *regular* C++ code with loops and Intel MKL versions.  The following is an abridged summary (please disregard lack of forward references, etc. in this -- that is unrelated to my question):

```
// Matrix.h

template <typename Type, typename IP>
class Matrix : public Matrix_Base<Type, IP>;

template <typename Matrix_Type>
class Matrix_Base{
    /* ... */

    // Matrix / Scalar addition
    template <typename T>
    Matrix_Base& operator+=(const T value_) { 
      return Implementation<IP>::Plus_Equal(
          static_cast<Matrix_Type&>(*this), value_);

    /* More operators and rest of code... */
    };

struct CPP;
struct MKL;

template <typename IP>
struct Implementation{
/* This struct contains static methods that do the actual operations */
```

The trouble that I'm having right now is related to the implementation of the Implementation class (no pun intended).  I know that I can use specialization of the Implementation template class to specialize `template <> struct Implementation<MKL>{/* ... */};` however, this will result in a lot of code duplication as there are a number of operators (such as matrix-scalar addition, subtraction, ... ) for which both the generic and the specialized versions use the same code.

So, instead, I thought that I could get rid of the template specialization and just use enable_if to provide different implementations for those operators which have different implementations when using MKL (or CUDA, etc.).

This has proven to me to be more challenging than I had originally expected.  The first -- for `operator += (T value_)` works fine.  I added in a check just to make sure that the parameter is reasonable (this can be eliminated if it is the source of my troubles, which I doubt).

```
template <class Matrix_Type, typename Type, typename enable_if< 
    std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value  >::type* dummy = nullptr>
static Matrix_Type& Plus_Equal(Matrix_Type& matrix_, Type value_){
    uint64_t total_elements = matrix_.actual_dims.first * matrix_.actual_dims.second;
    //y := A + b

    #pragma parallel 
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < total_elements; ++i)
        matrix_.Data[i] += value_; 

    return matrix_;
}
```

However, I am having a really hard time figuring out how to deal with `operator *=(T value_)`.  This is due to the fact that `float` and `double` have different implementations for MKL but not in the general case.

Here is the declaration.  Note that the 3rd parameter is a dummy parameter and was my attempt at forcing function overloading, since I cannot use partial template function specialization:

```
template <class Matrix_Type, typename U, typename Type = 
    typename internal::Type_Traits< Matrix_Type>::type, typename  enable_if<
    std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value >::type* dummy = nullptr>

static Matrix_Type& Times_Equal(Matrix_Type& matrix_, U value_, Type dummy_ = 0.0);
```

Definition for general case.  :

```
template<class IP>
template <class Matrix_Type, typename U, typename Type,  typename enable_if<
    std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value >::type* dummy>
Matrix_Type& Implementation<IP>::Times_Equal(Matrix_Type& matrix_, U value_, Type){

    uint64_t total_elements = matrix_.actual_dims.first * matrix_.actual_dims.second;

    //y := A - b
    #pragma parallel
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < total_elements; ++i)
        matrix_.Data[i] *= value_;

    return matrix_;
}
```

The trouble starts when I try to implement a specialization for MKL:

```
template<>
template <class Matrix_Type, typename U, typename Type, typename enable_if<
    std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value >::type* dummy>
Matrix_Type& Implementation<implementation::MKL>::Times_Equal(
    Matrix_Type& matrix_, 
    U value_,
    typename enable_if<std::is_same<Type,float>::value,Type>::type)
{

    float value = value_;

    MKL_INT total_elements = matrix_.actual_dims.first * matrix_.actual_dims.second;
    MKL_INT const_one = 1;

    //y := a * b
    sscal(&total_elements, &value, matrix_.Data, &const_one);
    return matrix_;
}
```

This gives me an error in clang:

_**error:** out-of-line definition of 'Times_Equal' does not match any declaration in 'Implementation'_

and in g++ (shortened somewhat)

_**error:** template-id `Times_Equal<>' for 'Matrix_Type& Implementation::Times_Equal(...)' does not match any template declaration.

The code compiles perfectly fine if I change the 3rd parameter to be Type, rather than having the enable_if.  But when I do that, I cannot see how to have separate implementations for float and double.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `typename enable_if< 
    std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value  >::type* dummy = nullptr` can also be implemented as `typename = enable_if< 
    std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value  >::type` which is a bit shorter ;)

Comment: *"Note that the 3rd parameter is a dummy parameter and was my attempt at forcing function overloading*" parameters with default-arguments are ignored for (normal) overload resolution. (They might still play a role in the partial ordering of function templates, IIRC.)

Comment: @DyP, your second point is well-taken; however, my understanding was that if Type was not equal to 'float', then the final parameter would cause substitution failure and the implementation would be excluded.  Apparently, I am wrong since it will not compile; however, I do not really understand what I am doing wrong here.  Note that without the default argument, I get into trouble with my general case implementation.  I suppose that I could always pass additional parameters to Implementation, but I'd rather not.  And I'd **much** rather have the template parameters deduced by the compiler.

Comment: You have a compiler error that says that you are defining a method that does not match any declaration in the class definition. Perhaps you should declare the overloads that you are defining?

Comment: Honestly, I'd use less `enable_if` and more tag dispatching.  And I'd do a `RootImplementation<Derived>` that uses CRTP to dispatch back to your `Implmentation<X>`, which are specialized based off of MKL vs standard.  SFINAE, but often a bad design decision.

Comment: @DyP just out of curiosity, what does "typename =" syntax mean?

Comment: @IgorR. It's just an unnamed template type parameter with a default argument.

Comment: @Casey, Frankly, I thought that I was declaring it properly.  I obviously am misunderstanding something -- possible something fundamental here.  I expected that the final parameter works out to float (since either Type is float, or else there is a substitution error) -- then in the definition I have a parameter of type float.  I thought that I was relatively thorough in going through the code and matching declarations and definitions before I posted the question.

Comment: @Yakk, I think your point regarding tag dispatching as a preferred approach to SFINAE.  Could you please elaborate a bit more about using CRTP.  I thought that this is what I am trying to do -- `template <class Matrix> class Matrix_Base<Matrix>` -- in this case Matrix_Base contains all of the common operations for the Matrix class.  Could you please provide a bit more information on this point?

Comment: The code you show is wrong in a few places. E.g. you cannot include inheritance in a forward declaration of a class, and your `Matrix_Base` template doesn't seem to have the right number of parameters. Can you clean that up please? Do we even need to know about the `Matrix` template?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be very tedious to implement using std::enable_if, as the general cases would have to be implemented with an enable_if that turned it on if it doesn't fit one of the specializations.

Specifically addressing your code, I don't think the compiler is able to deduce `Type` in your MKL specialization as it is hidden away in the std::enable_if, and thus this specialization would never get called.

Instead of using enable_if you could perhaps do something like this:

```
#include<iostream>

struct CPP {};
struct MKL {};

namespace Implementation
{
   //
   // general Plus_Equal
   //
   template<class Type, class IP>
   struct Plus_Equal
   {
      template<class Matrix_Type>
      static Matrix_Type& apply(Matrix_Type& matrix_, Type value_)
      {
         std::cout << " Matrix Plus Equal General Implementation " << std::endl;
         // ... do general Plus_Equal ...
         return matrix_;
      }
   };

   //
   // specialized Plus_Equal for MKL with Type double
   //
   template<>
   struct Plus_Equal<double,MKL>
   {
      template<class Matrix_Type>
      static Matrix_Type& apply(Matrix_Type& matrix_, double value_)
      {
         std::cout << " Matrix Plus Equal MKL double Implementation " << std::endl;
         // ... do MKL/double specialized Plus_Equal ...
         return matrix_;
      }
   };
} // namespace Implementation

template <typename Type, typename IP, typename Matrix_Type>
class Matrix_Base
{  
   public:
   // ... matrix base implementation ...

   // Matrix / Scalar addition
   template <typename T>
   Matrix_Base& operator+=(const T value_) 
   { 
      return Implementation::Plus_Equal<Type,IP>::apply(static_cast<Matrix_Type&>(*this), value_);
   }

   // ...More operators and rest of code...
};

template <typename Type, typename IP>
class Matrix : public Matrix_Base<Type, IP, Matrix<Type,IP> >
{
   // ... Matrix implementation ...
};

int main()
{
   Matrix<float ,MKL> f_mkl_mat;
   Matrix<double,MKL> d_mkl_mat;

   f_mkl_mat+=2.0; // will use general plus equal
   d_mkl_mat+=2.0; // will use specialized MKL/double version

   return 0;
}
```

Here I used class specialization instead of std::enable_if. I found that you were very inconsistent with the `IP`, `Type`, and `Matrix_Type` types in your examples, so I hope I use them correctly here.

As an aside in relation to the comments on std::enable_if. I would use the form

```
template<... , typename std::enable_if< some bool >::type* = nullptr> void func(...);
```

over

```
template<... , typename = std::enable_if< some bool >::type> void func(...);
```

as it enables you to do some function overloads you couldn't do with the other form.

Hope you can use it :)

**EDIT 20/12-13**: After re-reading my post i found that I should explicitly do CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern), which i added in the above code. I pass both `Type` and `IP` to `Matrix_Base`. If you find this tedious, one could instead provide a matrix traits class, from which `Matrix_Base` could take them out.

```
template<class A>
struct Matrix_Traits;

// Specialization for Matrix class
template<class Type, class IP>
struct Matrix_Traits<Matrix<Type,IP> >
{
   using type = Type;
   using ip   = IP;
};
```

Then `Matrix_Base`would now only take one template argument, namely the matrix class itself, and get the types from the traits class

```
template<class Matrix_Type>
class Matrix_Base
{
   // Matrix / Scalar addition
   template <typename T>
   Matrix_Base& operator+=(const T value_) 
   { 
      // We now get Type and IP from Matrix_Traits
      return Implementation::Plus_Equal<typename Matrix_Traits<Matrix_Type>::type
                                      , typename Matrix_Traits<Matrix_Type>::ip
                                      >::apply(static_cast<Matrix_Type&>(*this), value_);
   }
};
```